# React, Typescript, how to check key values

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this type:

```js
interface MyType {
   name: string
   age: number
   friend: Person
}
```

and consider this state:

```js
const [myState, setMyState] = useState<MyType>({.....})
```

and I have this function that changes a filed inside `useState`:

```js
const handleChange = (filed: keyof MyType, value: unknown) => {
   setMyState({
      ...myState,
      [field]: value
   })
}
```

how can I use generics or some other work around to type the `value` argument in the above function?
I expect my `handleChange` function to throw error when wrong value is passed to a field:

```js
handleChange("name", 5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add generic for `field` argument:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

type Person = {
  tag: 'Person'
}
interface MyType {
  name: string
  age: number
  friend: Person
}

declare const DEFAULT_STATE: MyType

const App = () => {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState<MyType>(DEFAULT_STATE)

  const handleChange = <Field extends keyof MyType>(field: Field, value: MyType[Field]) => {
    setMyState({
      ...myState,
      [field]: value
    })
  }

  handleChange('name', 'John') // ok
  handleChange('age', 'five') // expected error

}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mLylbW)

Comment: wish I could up-vote this twice.